# Using JQuery to animate a div to hide after set time but then able to access by a button to show/hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

Code has been amended and now it works as follows when you click on the page the div animates out to show. And if you click on the button it toggles the show and the hide div. But what it doesn't do is disappear after a minute when it first opens. still learning jquery so my code maybe a bit over all over the place.

```
   <script>
   var isOn = true;

    function getOff(){
    if(isOn){
    $("#button").trigger('click');
    }
      }

    $("#button").trigger('click');

    setTimeout("getOff()", 1000);


    $(document).ready(function() { 

      $("#button").toggle(function () {
         $("#expandText").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
         $("#button").css("background-image","url(images/Text_Expander_off.jpg)");
    },function () {
            $("#expandText").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
           $("#button").css("background-image","url(images/Text_Expander_on.jpg)");
    });
    });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isOn = true;

function getOff(){
if(isOn){
  $("#button").trigger('click');
  }
}

$("#button").trigger('click');

setTimeout("getOff()", 5000);
```

and set the isOn false if user presses the button

- edited, as I forgot the toggle thing

Comment: Thanks for this so just a warning that I am still learning jquery so try not laugh when you see how I have interpreted your code and applied it. So it now opens when you click on the page but it doesn't go away by itself. The button still works to toggle it on   and off. I will post my new code in the original question.

Comment: yeah, see you put it in wrong places, function must be outside jquery, ... Ill update my answer with this

Comment: ok I have had another attempt and it looks like I had some unnecessary code in there but I still don't quite understand how to get it to disappear after a minute. I will edited my answer so you can see the new code that i have. thanks @Steen

Comment: Please put link to your page back in question. Much easier to test suggestions with at live page. BUT: Think you just need to move the two lines  $("#button").trigger('click'); and setTimeout("getOff()", 1000); in to the jquery thing - last - right before the final });

Answer (score -1):

```
var timer;
var seconds=-1;
function hidediv(){
clearTimeout(timer);
seconds++;

if (secods == 60){
//hide div
return false;
}

timer= setTimeout(hidediv(), 1000);
}
```

on button click add

```
//call function
seconds();
```